# Android integer increments when activity is entered

Tags: android, android-activity, int, auto-increment, storing-data

Very Simple question. I want to update an `int` value, every time the user enters that `Activity` e.g.

first time entering `Activity` `int = 1`
second time entering `Activity` `int = 2` and so on..

This is the code I am using

```
public class confirmTaskForm extends FragmentActivity {

    private int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       id++;  
    }   
}
```

However every time the `Activity` is entered, the `int` value is always the same = 1. It might sound easy but i'd really appreciate help.

Comment: easy but fundamentally wrong answer: `private static int id = 0;`

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: it's wrong, u cant increment it

Comment: Do you want to keep this value even when the activty is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference outside of your Activity, as every time you navigate away it is reset or GC'd.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
     public static int myIdCache = 0;
}

public class confirmTaskForm extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         MyApplication.myIdCache++;  
    }   
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
  android:name="com.my.package.MyApplication"
  ... other things
```

The above is not a good recommended coding practice

---

You can also keep state using `SharedPreferences`

```
public class confirmTaskForm extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences();
       prefs.edit().putInteger("id", prefs.getInteger("id", 0) + 1).commit();

       Log.d("TAG", "Id is: " + prefs.getInteger("id"));  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in sharedPreferences :

```
private int id=0;
protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFromPreference();
    id++;
    saveInPreference();
}

private void getFromPreference() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    id = prefs.getInt("Count", -1);
}

private void saveInPreference() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("Count", id);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `id static` or put it in `SharedPreferences` if you want to keep counting even if your application restarts.

You may use this code to keep counter in `SharedPreference`.

```
private int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // getting shared preferences.
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
         // getting already saved count -  0 in case of first time
        int startCount = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
        // update count                
        startCount++;
        //restoring updated value
        getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",startCount).commit();

        count = startCount;
      }
```

Comment: "In short words" is right. This should be a comment if you don't care to elaborate and add something that isn't already in an answer.